# Dynamically ended function for dynamically created video tag

Tags: jquery, html, video

I've got a button which creates a video tag:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
  var video = $('<video />', {
    id: 'myVid',
    src: "vid1.mp4",
    type: 'video/mp4',
    controls: false
  });
  $('body').append(video);
  var btn = $('<button id="btnPP">Play Video</button>');
  $('body').append(btn);
});
$(document).on('ended', "#myVid", function() {
  alert("fini");
});
```

The code to me seems okay, however when the video ends, it won't execute any code inside the `ended` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the video doesn't exist on the page, even on `.ready()`. As such, you won't be able to target it with `$(document).on()`, even with **bubbling**. Instead, you need to add an [**event listener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). I've added an event listener to the `ended` event and ensured that the target is a video in the following example. I've also added an `autoplay` to show that the video will trigger the event once ended:

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  var video = $('<video />', {
    id: 'myVid',
    src: "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4",
    type: 'video/mp4',
    controls: false,
    autoplay: true
  });
  $('body').append(video);
  var btn = $('<button id="btnPP">Play Video</button>');
  $('body').append(btn);
});

document.addEventListener('ended', function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('video')){
        alert('fini');
    }
}, true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Test</button>
```

Hope this helps! :)